# In anylogic index function, how can I use triangular distribution or any other random int?

Tags: properties, anylogic, inject, triangular

I'm making a container terminal simulation.
[discription of the sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0smh.png)

When the ship arrives to the port by 'sourceDeliveryShips1',
delay happens as the ship unloads.
When unloading, I want to use the inject function to create different numbers as each ship arrives.
[unloading's inject function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnXgj.png)

In unloading1-Delay > Actions > On Enter, I wrote this code.
`sourceContainers1.inject((int) Math.floor(triangular(150, 200, 300)));`

However, there is error when I start the simulation.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMVDe.png)

Please help me... Is there any other way I can make random numbers of the ships' containers?

It works fine when I use int like :
`sourceContainers1.inject(100);`
But I want to make the number 100 change every time a ship arrives.

I tried changing the code to

`sourceContainers1.inject((int) Math.round(triangular(150, 200, 300)));`

`sourceContainers1.inject((int) uniform_discr(70,90));`

But nothing seems to work..

Comment: Always build little example models to check the actual root cause. I just built a simple `Source` inject block and a button that runs `source.inject((int)Math.floor(triangular(150, 200, 300)));` . It works flawlessly. Try it yourself. Your problem is somewhere else. Try to eliminate other variations to see what is truly causing this behavior, then open a new issue with that :)

Comment: One side comment: the API for `triangular` has `triangular(min, max, mode)`, be careful with the *Sequence* of your arguments always (use code-complete to check them) :)